# Considering the function $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, determine the largest subset where $h$ is crescent.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\large h(x)=\int_{-2}^xe^{s^2-4}(s^3-4s)ds$$

Maybe there is some rule or definition which i lost in the "Calculus path" that can show me what the question wants without doing this integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate h is I think a good start.
$h'(x)=e^{x^2-4}(x^3-4x)$
then evaluate where $h>0$, as $\forall x,e^{x^2-4} > 0$ evaluate when $(x^3-4x) > 0$ i.e. $x^3>4x$ which means $x(x^2-4)>0$ and do a sign evaluation.

So we have $h'(x) > 0$ when $x\in ]-2;0[\cup]2;\infty[$

Please verify it as I wrote it quickly without a pen.